# Force localization for os.date()

Tags: php, c++, lua, localization

I'm building a server reporting system in Lua and C++, using the SMFL library and I've got a bit stuck on a potential issue.
The target of this script is that it creates a HTML file (with PHP within it) and uploads it to my webserver, for reporting purposes.
The name of the upload file will be '[process id]*[client IP]*[date].php', so we'll get something like '1234_199.123.45.7_31/01/2014.php', and clearly the date format needs to be in the European format.

I use the `os.date("%x")`, but it reports the date in the local machine's regional type, but it needs to be the dd/mm/yyyy format, regardless of the region settings of the client.

I've looked on how to do this, but I've only been able to get the time offset and not force `os.date("%x")` to use a specific region.

How can I force`os.date("%x")` to use the dd/mm/yyyy format?

Comment: Try `print(os.date'%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yeah, that worked. Post your that as a solution, and I'll set it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua's [os.date accepts a format specifier](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.date), which is same as strftime. Based on [strftime's docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/), the format you want is obtained via

```
os.date("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
os.date("*t")
```

This returns a table with the date-time components, like:

[image]

With this data you can build a custom formatting function, based in T.day, T.month and T.year